# ranking and sorting pandas dataframe according to a specific column

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.DataFrame([['b',40], ['cd',2], ['sf',20], ['sdf',30]],
                 columns=['a','score'])
```

This is the dataframe I have.I want to rank the dataframe according to the score in decreading order and then sort them accordingly.

I tried using df.rank with groupby but it didnt work.

expected output-

```
    a   score   Rank
0   b   40      1.0
1   sdf 30      2.0
2   sf  20      3.0
3   cd   2      4.0
```

Comment: `s.sort_values('score', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)`, `s['Rank']  = s.index+1`

Comment: @AChampion this doesnt work when I run it....are s.sort_values('score', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True) and s['Rank'] = s.index+1 separate lines?

Comment: `a = (s.sort_values('score', ascending= False))`
and for Rank Column, use this 
`a['Rank'] = range(1, len(a)+ 1)
`